# Containers are not appear, how can work arrange these in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm flutter begginner. I tried to make a listview and make some containers and text widgets. but there's only text widget and don't appear containers that have images. Could you review where's some problems in code below.

```
class  DonatePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DonatePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
            ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            reverse: true,
            addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,

            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 400,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("assets/images/components/shop/donate/card2.png")
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Campaign of the week"),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 400,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("assets/images/components/shop/donate/card1.png")
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("for good"),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 400,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("assets/images/components/shop/donate/card3.png")
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              )
            ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Problems Screenshots below.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are probably not calling the images properly, share your `pubspec.yaml` and a screenshot of your folder structure where you put your images.

Comment: @Denzel Thanks.I attached pictures above. Could check that please? I put the images in container that in donate folder in assets folder, and I put that in pubspec.yaml and did pub get but they're not loaded.

Comment: oh I did not attached '/' in the path. Thanks..!!

Comment: @Denzel Do you know why the path 'assets/' can't load asset's below folders and have to write the path like 'assets/a/b/c' when I want to load c?

Answer (score 1):

Please add folder path like this:

- assets/images/components/shop/donate/